# How to display hex digit string with space on text control in wxpython?

Tags: text, wxpython, controls

I want to input hex digit with key stroke or copy and paste on text control.
My input is displayed bytes with space.
When "12345678" is typed those are displayed "12 34 56 78" on text control.
I am tring to it with EVT_TEXT event.
But I can't resolve it.

Comment: A masked textctrl may be what you are looking for, located in wx.lib.masked.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: I have the following implementation. The way to go, is to handle `EVT_KEY_DOWN` , instead of `EVT_TEXT`  Hope it helps:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import wx

###########################################################################
## Display hex digit string with space on text control in wxpython;
## input hex digit with key stroke or copy and paste on text control
###########################################################################

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):    
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = "INPUT DEMO", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 200,150 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_staticText1 = wx.StaticText( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, u"HEX STRING", (-1, 10), wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_textCtrl1 = wx.TextCtrl( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, (-1, 30), wx.Size(190, -1), 0 )
        self.Layout()       
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_textCtrl1.Bind( wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyPress)
        # Disable right-click menu (optional)
        self.m_textCtrl1.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.skip)
        self.Show()

    def skip( self, event ):
        """
        Disable right click menu popup
        """
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def onKeyPress( self, event ):
        """
        Key press event handler
        """
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()

        if event.ControlDown() and keycode == 67:
            # ctrl + c pressed
            clipdata = wx.TextDataObject()
            text_string = self.m_textCtrl1.GetValue()
            clipdata.SetText(text_string)
            wx.TheClipboard.Open()
            wx.TheClipboard.SetData(clipdata)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()

        elif event.ControlDown() and keycode == 86:
            # ctrl + v pressed
            self.paste()

        elif 48<= keycode <= 57 or 324<= keycode <= 333:
            self.justify()
            event.Skip()

        elif 65 <= keycode <= 70: # or 97 <= keycode <= 102:            
            self.justify()
            self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText(chr(keycode))
            self.justify()

        # When backspace, Del,<- and -> Pressed
        elif  event.GetKeyCode() in [ 8, 127, 314, 316 ]: 
            event.Skip()            

    def justify( self ):
        """
        Fill space to typed string if required
        """
        curPos = self.m_textCtrl1.GetInsertionPoint()           
        self.m_textCtrl1.AppendText(" " * ((curPos + 1)%3 == 0))

    def paste(self):
        """
        Paste Hex string from clipboard
        """
        if not wx.TheClipboard.IsOpened():  # may crash, otherwise
            do = wx.TextDataObject()
            wx.TheClipboard.Open()
            success = wx.TheClipboard.GetData(do)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
            if success:
                s = re.sub('[^\da-fA-F]+', '', do.GetText())
                if s:
                    toPaste = " ".join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
                    self.m_textCtrl1.SetValue(toPaste.upper())  
                    self.justify()
                    self.m_textCtrl1.SetInsertionPointEnd()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame1(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I have test your code. It works correctly